# MemCached client with Delphi

Tags: delphi, memcached

Hallo, Does anyone perhaps know how to interface with a MemCached server (linux) from within a Delphi win32 application?
I am unable to find a general C DLL client, or perhaps delphi code to communicate to the server.
Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Eric Grobler

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819544/are-there-any-caching-frameworks-for-delphi, voting to close this one.

Comment: Related, but not an exact duplicate. Just because the answer to question A also answers question B doesn't mean A and B are duplicates.

Comment: @Rob: Well, there is no option "close enough to a duplicate that it doesn't make sense to have this question too", which IMO applies here.

Comment: @Eric: As can be seen from the comments to the linked other question there is libmemcached, which according to the website can be built as a DLL to be used from a Delphi program.

Answer (score 3):

A Delphi client for Memcached can be found on google code:

http://code.google.com/p/delphimemcache/

Answer (score 2):

Since the protocol is fairly simple, just about any library which handles telnet should be able to handle communication with the server.  This includes [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx), [Synapse](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php), and [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html?redirTo=/products/ics.html).  I based this off of the protocol [documentation](http://code.sixapart.com/svn/memcached/trunk/server/doc/protocol.txt).

My preference would be to implement using Synapse.  Synapse uses an object model rather than a component model, and is very easy to use and extend.  The latest developers version (available via SVN) supports Delphi 2009 and I would expect soon to support Delphi 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback, I will try a telnet communication.
(and have a look at Synapse)

Regards
Eric