# Is there a way to allow Delphi applications to use Hazelcast?

Tags: delphi, hazelcast

Is there any way for a Delphi application to use the distributed cache from [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends - a small Java bridge service, using a simple object serialization (JSON) or a efficient custom serialization, would surely work. It could be implemented as a server with Grizzly, Netty or similar libraries. For a protoype, you could use a simple Java based HTTP server which the Delphi client connects to.

If you are not bound to use Hazelcast, there is a [Delphi client library](http://code.google.com/p/delphimemcache/) for [memcached](http://memcached.org/). See [MemCached client with Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334358/memcached-client-with-delphi)

Answer (score 3):

Hazelcast support memcache protocol. You can use a Delphi memcache client library to access Hazelcast cluster.